# Ни к чему не принадлежащая полоска ContextMenu c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Я пытаюсь кастомизировать ContextMenuStrip.

В итоге смог самостоятельно зарендерить toolStripSeparator, поменять цвет при наведении и ещё по мелочам.
Вот то, что вышло

[image: мой ContextMenuStrip]

Осталась эта **белая полоска слева**. Она является частью ImageMargin, т.е. частью места под картинку, и как убрать её - не понятно(а если убрать imageMargin, то полоска остаётся)

Дальше идут нерабочие способы, можно и не читать, если не хочется.

Главный вопрос - **что это за полоска и как её убрать?**

(даже все способы вместе не сработали :< )

Пытался поменять toolStripMenuItem.Margin, BackColor, contextMenu.BackColor, но не помогло.

Попытался самостоятельно поменять цвет через ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

```cs
contextMenu.Renderer = new MyMenuRenderer();
public class MyMenuRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyMenuRenderer() : base(new BrowserColors()) { }
}
public class BrowserColors : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin { get { return Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0); } }
    // ImageMarginGradientMiddle и ImageMarginGradientEnd, как оказалось, ни на что не влияют
}
```

Но при наведении на элемент это полоска оставалась видна.  После этого я попытался сделать так

```
contextMenu.ShowImageMargin = false;
contextMenu.ShowCheckMargin = false;
```

Полоска покрасилась в цвет contextMenu, **но не исчезла**.
(И как это так получается, что если убираешь imageMargin, остаётся imageMargin?)

Даже так попытался

```
public class MyContextMenuStrip : ContextMenuStrip
{
    protected override Padding DefaultPadding { get { return new Padding(0, 0, 0, 1); } }
}
```

Убрались все отступы. Кроме полоски.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать это возможно. Например в дискорде

[image: contextmenu discord]

**Логичный вопрос - что это за полоска и как её убрать?**

Comment: есть прога - Snoop, там можно найти эту рамку и "прибить" её.

Comment: `Сделать это возможно. Например в дискорде` - хах, а вы думаете, что он написан на WinForms?) Сам WinForms на столько древний, на сколько это возможно и он не был предназначен для дизайна. Хотите использовать C# и делать красивый дизайн, используйте WPF, ибо в WinForms вам в такие дебри надо залезть для изменения одной полосочки, из за которых вы рано или поздно скажете "А нафиг это надо". А и да, Discord написан на React, а это HTML, CSS, JS и другие веб разработки, которые позволяют сделать многое.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Я знаю что он не на winforms написан. Но мне уже чисто из принципа хочется всё на нём всё сделать. :)